# Erro ao passar de String para float e de float para String

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho um código que adiciona certos valores a uma lista de Strings mas parece que quando eu os converto para float depois para String outra vez eles não são adicionados! Qual é o problema ?

Código em que eles sao adicionados :

```
if(media.size()!=0){       
    medias.add(media.get(media.size()-1).text());
}
```

Código em que eles não são adicionados :

```
if(media.size()!=0){
    Float media_float = Float.valueOf(media.get(media.size()-1).text());
    media_float = media_float /10;
    String media_string = String.valueOf(media_float);
    medias.add(media_string);
}
```

Aqui esta o código completo :

```
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try  {

                String site1 = "http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/indcurso.asp?letra=";
                Document document;

                Elements lista;

                document = Jsoup.connect(site1 +letra_value).get();

                Elements boxes = document.select("div.box10");


                for (Element box : boxes) {

                    String linAreaC1 = box.select(".lin-area-c1").text();
                    String linAreaC2 = box.select(".lin-area-c2").text();
                    String linAreaC3 = box.select(".lin-area-c3").text();

                    codigoCurso.add(linAreaC1);
                    curso.add(linAreaC2);


                    Element linCurso = box.nextElementSibling();

                    while (linCurso.hasClass("lin-curso")) {
                        String linCursoC2 = linCurso.select(".lin-curso-c2").text();
                        String linCursoC3 = linCurso.select(".lin-curso-c3").text();
                        String linCursoC4 = linCurso.select(".lin-curso-c4").text();


                        codigoFaculdade.add(linCursoC2);
                        faculades.add(linCursoC3);

                        linCurso = linCurso.nextElementSibling();
                    }
                    faculades_main.add(faculades);
                    faculades = new ArrayList<String>();
                    codigosFaculdade.add(codigoFaculdade);
                    codigoFaculdade= new ArrayList<String>();
                }


                for(int contador=0;contador<faculades_main.size();contador++){
                    String codigoFaculdadi;
                    String codigoCursi;


                    codigoCursi = codigoCurso.get(contador);


                    for(int i=0;i<codigosFaculdade.get(contador).size();i++){
                        codigoFaculdadi=codigosFaculdade.get(contador).get(i);
                        String site = "http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/detcursopi.asp?codc="+codigoCursi+"&code="+codigoFaculdadi;
                        Document document1 = Jsoup.connect(site).get();

                        Elements media = document1.select(".tvag");



                        if(media.size()!=0){
                            medias.add(media.get(media.size()-1).text());
                        }else {
                            medias.add("N/A");
                        }




                    }
                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            prepareListData();



        }

    };
```

Comment: Fiz um teste e funcionou perfeitamente seu exemplo, tem certeza que a variável `media_float` está sendo preenchida corretamente?

Comment: Sim da maneira que eu disse no primeiro exemplo da , mas no segundo não , não percebo

Comment: Se quiser posso postar o código todo

Comment: Faça isso, edite seu post por favor, nos mostre onde você cria esse estrutura `media` e onde ela é preenchida

Comment: Elements é uma estrutura que vc implementou?

Comment: Tem certeza que a variável String não está ficando nula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testei esse programa, mas mandei imprimir o conteúdo de `medias` (para letra "A"). Aqui alguns dos *números* excluindo os N/A:

> ```
>  140,2
>  141,0
>  150,4
>  124,8
> ```

como podemos ver, esses textos contem uma vírgula e portanto **não é** um float válido (em Java) - o `Float.valueOf` e o `Float.parseFloat` somente aceitam o **ponto** como separador!

*Estranho esse seu código não ter jogado uma*

> ```
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "140,2"
> ```

Use o `NumberFormat` para fazer a convesão (eventualmente passando um `Locale`):

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));

...

    String texto = media.get(media.size()-1).text();
    try {
        float media_float = numberFormat.parse(texto).floatValue();
        ...
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

note tambem que estou usando o `float` com letra pequena para fazer os cálculos...

Answer (score 2):

**Tenha certeza** que o valor que você recebe como `string` inicialmente pode ser convertido em `float`(que sua `string` inicial corresponde à apenas números).
Troque o `valorStr` para sua variável `String` correpondente

Exemplo de código funcional:

```java
String valorStr = "55";
Float media_float = Float.parseFloat(valorStr);
media_float = media_float / 10;
String media_string = Float.toString(media_float);
//medias.add(media_string); #comentei apenas para nao criar a coleção

System.out.println(media_string); //mostra 5.5
```

Comment: Eu tenho a certeza que é ! Não percebo porque não esta a adicionar nada a lista..

Comment: Com certeza, não coloquei junto porque acredito que o local certo de testar isso é no momento de popular a coleção

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar o **parseFloat** e **toString**, exemplo:

De String pra float

```
float f = Float.parseFloat("25");
```

De float pra String

```
String s = Float.toString(25.0f);
```